# Having trouble finding the best way to search

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to find a node.js module or some script or make something to search though data and find the most relevant results. I was originally going to use google custom search API to search the steam community market but I think that's unnecessary and limited. But before that I was ripping apart the string and putting it back together and getting price data from steam individually, it worked practically perfect but it was messy and limited.

I now use an API to get all the steam csgo market data, i need to search it for the most relevant result.

A query for the below might look like 'stained bs' 'karambit stained fn' 'st stained ft'

```
        "★ Karambit | Stained (Battle-Scarred)": {
            "last_updated": 1439785289,
            "quantity": 5,
            "value": 18855
        },
        "★ Karambit | Stained (Factory New)": {
            "last_updated": 1439785289,
            "quantity": 5,
            "value": 26499 // yea thats $265 for a purely cosmetic digital item
        },
        "★ Karambit | Stained (Field-Tested)": {
            "last_updated": 1439785289,
            "quantity": 10,
            "value": 20000
        },
        "★ Karambit | Stained (Minimal Wear)": {
            "last_updated": 1439785289,
            "quantity": 10,
            "value": 20223
        },
        "★ Karambit | Stained (Well-Worn)": {
            "last_updated": 1439785289,
            "quantity": 8,
            "value": 19302
        },
```

I am having trouble knowing what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js community have de Node Package Manager (npm) that is a command line utility and a public repository.

Using the search feature on npmjs.com you can find very useful modules.

Also github.com is a public site with tons of Node.js or just JavaScript modules. You can use their "explore" feature and filter by language  to find useful client and server side code

If you already have installed npm. So you can use:

```
npm search <ANYTERM>
```

Comment: I've got one called didyoumean but see didYouMean(input, list, key)